# Worldpay payment integration post two times in Drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, worldpay

I am trying to store Worldpay payment responses with the username. But the problem is that it is storing the response POST data from Worldpay in the database twice. First it stores the payment responses in the database properly but the username as null, and then it will save only my username as a new row and all other values as null.

My code:

```
function response_success() {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $trans_time   = strtotime($_POST['transTime']);
    $trans_date   = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $trans_time);
    $trans_id     = intval($_POST['transId']);
    $future_payid = intval($_POST['futurePayId']);
    $trans_status = $_POST['transStatus'];
    $authamnt     = $_POST['authAmount'];
    $authcurr     = $_POST['authCurrency'];
    $authamntstring = $_POST['authAmountString'];
    $auth_msg     = $_POST['rawAuthMessage'];
    $auth_code    = $_POST['rawAuthCode'];
    $callbck_pw   = $_POST['callbackPW'];
    $card_typ     = $_POST['cardType'];
    $cntry_match  = $_POST['countryMatch'];
    $avs          = intval($_POST['AVS']);
    print_r($_POST['email']);
    $bw_paymentinfo_add_query = db_insert('test')
    ->fields(array(
        'transactionid' => $trans_id,
        'futurepayid' =>$future_payid,
        'transaction_status' => $trans_status,
        'transaction_time' => $trans_date,
        'auth_amount' => $authamnt,
        'auth_currency' => $authcurr,
        'auth_amount_string' =>$authamntstring ,
        'raw_auth_message' => $auth_msg,
        'raw_auth_code' => $auth_code,
        'callback_pw' => $callbck_pw,
        'card_type' => $card_typ,
        'country_match' => $cntry_match,
        'avs' => $avs,
        'email' => $email,
    ))
    ->execute();
    drupal_set_message('Your transaction has been successful');
}
```